# Android - Activity persist as destroyed after call startActivity

Tags: android, android-activity

This is the problem´s cenary:

The Activity "A" have a button than call startActivity B.

The Activity "B" have a button then call finish(). So the app show Activity "A" again.

Now, If i call activity "B" the property **mDestroyed = true**

The problem:
**When i access B a second time B is destroyed**

**Why B continue destroyed after i call startActivity?**

Someone can help me?

**ManifestFile:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.xxxxxx">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="xxx"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".BaseActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".A"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".B"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Activity B method:**

```
 @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
```

**Activity A method:**

```
   @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, B.class));
                    }
```

**When i acess B a second time:**
[image: When i acess B a second time]

Comment: What is the actual problem?  Can you access the B activity a second time and does it behave normally?

Comment: Execuse me. It looks so funny. 'Please, help, I've got a local var':)

Comment: The problem is:

When i acess B a second time B is destroyed.

Comment: @user2525275 so make  your question readable. change it

Comment: @user2525275 how do you call?

Comment: post manifest file

Comment: oh gosh , please, post your code

Comment: Question adjusted guys. Tks by the attention!

Answer (score 2):

`finish()` method calls `onDestroy()` of activity . Replace `finish()` with

```
startActivity(new Intenet(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class));
```

Your current activity will be in background.

Comment: Hi Jan, tks by the answer, but i really want know why "B" activity continue destroyed after i call startActivity...